# PHP | Switch statement crashes execution

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have this statement that includes in a php-file. And with it execution crashes. Nothing executes before and after the statement.

```
    switch ($type) {
    case "contact_page" :
        $subject = "Вопрос со страницы Контакты";
        $user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        break;
    case "call_ask" :
        $subject = "Просьба позвонить";
        break;
    case "calculator" :
        $subject = "Калькулятор";
        $user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        break;
    default :
        $output = json_encode(['type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Запрос из неверного типа формы.']);
        die($output);
}
```

When I replace this with `if...else` statement all executes good.
Can't find a mistake.

Comment: so start commenting out each of those lines and figure out which one causes the crash. there's nothing that looks wrong.

Comment: @KA_lin: pointless+useless. default's the last in that switch, so there's no need for a break, and break is not REQUIRED anywhere, so the presence/absence of a break cannot cause a crash.

Comment: how you are calling this function? and what is the output of `var_dump($type);`?

Comment: @MarcB You are right

Comment: Looks like the problem is some crazy character is hiding somewhere.

Comment: What php versrion are you using?

Comment: Not working: https://ideone.com/KGAWcg

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the Russian text?

Comment: @MarcB I tried this before writing. Compiling stops in the first _case_ or _default_ , even when I leave only _default_ it isn't work. Or changing to _case_ steps to numbers. When I leave empty _switch_ without nothing, then execution.

Comment: @KA_lin php is 5.3.29.

Comment: @Anant even with constant value or only _default_ nothing works. And _if...else_ works, but it is not an issue.

Comment: Are you getting errors? If so, please show them.

Comment: @PraveenKumar no, Russian is only the value. And this language exists later too. Also _if...else_ works.

Comment: @PaulBurilichev Grrr... True that. Do one thing. Wrap the Russian content with some English text before and after and see? Just check?

Comment: @PraveenKumar we've got the answer!
many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php version does not support the new array notation (5.4+ from what I know).

Use in the `default` case:

```
 $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Запрос из неверного типа формы.'));
```

Comment: Yes, it is the problem.
Thank you for attention. Really I forget this.

Comment: That's funny that people still in old versions of PHP. For example I use always latest release of PHP (now v. 7) and I don't care if there will be exceptions, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade PHP to >5.4

or update code from:

```
json_encode(['type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Запрос из неверного типа формы.']);
```

to

```
json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Запрос из неверного типа формы.'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't upgrade php and haven't permission. And, yes, this is the issue.

Comment: oh... those admins... (: